# Reading the direct data of the Realtime database with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This might seem a copy, but I can't find my answer on the internet. Here's what I want to:
[image: The image]

I tried using the normal database.ref() things, but it is a direct data from the database, not in a ref group (like products, users etc.)

My code (the <> areas are writed correctly and working):

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: <>,
    authDomain: <>,
    databaseURL: <>,
    projectId: <>,
    storageBucket: <>,
    messagingSenderId: <>,
    appId: <>
  };


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        const database = firebase.database();

        var test;

        database.ref("password").on('value',function(snapshot) {
            test = snapshot.val();
        });

        console.log(test);
```

But this just didn't work. (console just gives `undefined` message)

So, how can I access this data (the password from the screenshot) from my database?

Comment: Your question should show what code you tried and explain what it's doing that's different than what you expect, along with any errors or output. Right now what you have is too vague to answer.

Comment: @DougStevenson editing right now

Comment: Put the log in the database callback. The callback is asynchronous meaning it returns right away before the result is ready. The log will not show you the value where it is now.

Comment: what do you mean by a callback? (note: the `password` thing will stay on there and not will be changed to another value. i just need to read the value from javascript)

Comment: You're going to have to learn about callbacks and asynchronous programming in order to make effective use of Firebase.  Without this background, a lot of what Firebase does will be confusing to you.